# clang error - CUDA directory not found on OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, cuda, clang, pycuda

I’m trying to install a CUDA package in Python called PyCUDA under OSX Maverics on a MacBook Pro 15” retina, but when trying to compile the files I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F /Library/Frameworks -framework CUDA'
ld: file not found: @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I think that at this stage PyCUDA is trying to compile some of it's C components.

I researched the error online and the solution proposed was to add -F/Library/Frameworks and -framework CUDA to the arguments list, but the make still fails with the error above.

I have CUDA 5.5 installed and Xcode command line tools as well. Also I am installing from the command line (not Xcode) using:

```
python setup.py install
```

Which, in turn calls clang to compile some of the components.

I think the @rpath part of the path is not processed correctly.

Any way I could resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error, but I managed to install pycuda using this 
http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Mac

Especially I used  siteconf.py as specified in the instructions.

```
BOOST_INC_DIR = []                                                              
BOOST_LIB_DIR = []                                                              
BOOST_COMPILER = 'gcc43'                                                        
USE_SHIPPED_BOOST = True                                                        
BOOST_PYTHON_LIBNAME = ['boost_python-py27']                                    
BOOST_THREAD_LIBNAME = ['boost_thread']                                         
CUDA_TRACE = False                                                              
CUDA_ROOT = '/usr/local/cuda'                                                   
CUDA_ENABLE_GL = False                                                          
CUDA_ENABLE_CURAND = True                                                       
CUDADRV_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib']                    
CUDADRV_LIBNAME = ['cuda']                                                      
CUDART_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib']                     
CUDART_LIBNAME = ['cudart']                                                     
CURAND_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib']                     
CURAND_LIBNAME = ['curand']                                                     
CXXFLAGS = ["-arch", "x86_64", "-arch", "i386"]                                 
LDFLAGS = ["-F/Library/Frameworks", "-arch", "x86_64", "-arch", "i386"]         
CXXFLAGS.extend(['-isysroot', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk'])
LDFLAGS.extend(['-isysroot', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk'])
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason my compiler was targeting the 10.5 OSX version, leading to compilation errors. Removing the "-arch", "i386" parts fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `export LDFLAGS="-F/Library/Frameworks/"` to your `.profile`.

Then `pip` can successfully install `pycuda`, at least on my Macbook with Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this procedure with `Python2.7` or `Python3.4`

First, I installed boost libraries:

```
$brew install boost
$brew install boost-python
```

Second, you create a file `$HOME/.aksetup-defaults.py` with content:

```
CUDA_ROOT = '/usr/local/cuda'
CUDADRV_LIBNAME = ['cuda']
CUDADRV_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib']
CUDART_LIBNAME = ['cudart']
CUDART_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib']
CUDA_ENABLE_CURAND = True
CUDA_ENABLE_GL = True
CUDA_INC_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/include']
CUDA_TRACE = False
CURAND_LIBNAME = ['curand']
CURAND_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib']
USE_SHIPPED_BOOST = True
```

Finally, install pycuda using pip

```
$python -m pip install pycuda
```

Voila! Start using `pycuda`